# Python - Remove 'group' in text file

Tags: python

Rookie to Python here...

I've been writing to text files using Pythons basic `open` and `write` commands, but I'm now needing to remove an entire group of text within said file.

Say this is the contents of `levels.txt`:

```
[Level 1]
1=Values
2=More Values
3=string

[Level 2]
1=lol
2=lolol
```

I want to remove everything in the `Level 2` group. How could I do that? If I use `write` it just appends.

Comment: One way: read in the contents as a string, modify that string, write the modified string, overwriting the old contents.

Comment: can you show what you have attempted? sounds like you are opening the file in `a` mode

Comment: Is the file formatted as `.ini` or `.toml` or something else by chance? You might be able to parse the file using a library like `configparser`, remove the group, and write it back down. Alternatively, you can scan the file, find the group, and delete all subsequent lines until you find the next group.

Comment: Are you doing `w` or `w+` at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and work it with regex.

**Considering your data will be of the same pattern:**

```
import re
with open("levels.txt", "r") as f:
     lines = f.read()
     updated_content = re.sub("\s+\[Level 2](\s[0-9]=[a-zA-Z]*)*", '', lines)

with open("levels_replaced.txt", "w") as f:
     f.write(updated_content)
```

The new updated file name is levels_replaced.txt.

Comment: The canonical solution is to write the filtered output to a temporary file, and once done replace the original file with the new one. This avoids loosing data if something goes wrong while writing to the file.

Comment: I changed it the same way you suggested and saved the content in the newer file.

Comment: Then your code is still missing the last part (replacing the original file by the new one). Hint: it's just one simple `os` package function call..

Comment: Oh, and I'm not sure regexps are the best tool here... Remember that the text file posted by the OP is just an example and that this obviously has to work for real-life data which may be quite different. Better to iterate over the file line by line, flag when we enter the desired section and skip lines until the next section begins.